# mysql get the sum of unique date

Tags: mysql, sql, select, aggregate-functions, mysql-error-1064

From MySQL table I have the list amount based on the dates. I need to get the sum of amount for each date:

ex:

```
id  type    date    amount  
1   1   2015-01-01  100
2   1   2015-01-01  150
3   1   2015-01-02  10
4   1   2015-01-03  250
```

Here 2015-01-01 appears more than once.

so i need the result like

```
date    amount  
2015-01-01  200
2015-01-02  10
2015-01-03  250
```

My Query getting between this week start and end

```
 SELECT * from mytable WHERE YEARWEEK(`date`) = YEARWEEK(CURRENT_DATE) AND `type` = 1 ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a `group by` clause:

```
SELECT   `date`, SUM(amount)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY `date`
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the result should be

```
date    amount  
2015-01-01  250
2015-01-02  10
2015-01-03  250
```

you can use this mysql query to get that result:

```
Select date, sum(amount) as amount 
from mytable 
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date asc
```

dont forget to add "ORDER BY" clause if you want the result in good order

Answer (score 1):

Use **GROUP BY**

Use **AS** clause to change the column Name

```
SELECT   `date`, SUM(amount) AS amount 
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY `date`
```